# Get MM-DD-YYYY from pandas Timestamp

Tags: python, date, pandas

dates seem to be a tricky thing in python, and I am having a lot of trouble simply stripping the date out of the pandas TimeStamp. I would like to get from `2013-09-29 02:34:44` to simply `09-29-2013`

I have a dataframe with a column Created_date:

```
Name: Created_Date, Length: 1162549, dtype: datetime64[ns]`
```

I have tried applying the `.date()` method on this Series, eg: `df.Created_Date.date()`, but I get the error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'`

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`map` over the elements:

```
In [239]: from operator import methodcaller

In [240]: s = Series(date_range(Timestamp('now'), periods=2))

In [241]: s
Out[241]:
0   2013-10-01 00:24:16
1   2013-10-02 00:24:16
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [238]: s.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
Out[238]:
0    01-10-2013
1    02-10-2013
dtype: object

In [242]: s.map(methodcaller('strftime', '%d-%m-%Y'))
Out[242]:
0    01-10-2013
1    02-10-2013
dtype: object
```

You can get the raw `datetime.date` objects by calling the `date()` method of the `Timestamp` elements that make up the `Series`:

```
In [249]: s.map(methodcaller('date'))

Out[249]:
0    2013-10-01
1    2013-10-02
dtype: object

In [250]: s.map(methodcaller('date')).values

Out[250]:
array([datetime.date(2013, 10, 1), datetime.date(2013, 10, 2)], dtype=object)
```

Yet *another* way you can do this is by calling the unbound `Timestamp.date` method:

```
In [273]: s.map(Timestamp.date)
Out[273]:
0    2013-10-01
1    2013-10-02
dtype: object
```

This method is the fastest, and IMHO the most readable. `Timestamp` is accessible in the top-level `pandas` module, like so: `pandas.Timestamp`. I've imported it directly for expository purposes.

The `date` attribute of `DatetimeIndex` objects does something similar, but returns a `numpy` object array instead:

```
In [243]: index = DatetimeIndex(s)

In [244]: index
Out[244]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-10-01 00:24:16, 2013-10-02 00:24:16]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [246]: index.date
Out[246]:
array([datetime.date(2013, 10, 1), datetime.date(2013, 10, 2)], dtype=object)
```

For larger `datetime64[ns]` `Series` objects, calling `Timestamp.date` is faster than `operator.methodcaller` which is slightly faster than a `lambda`:

```
In [263]: f = methodcaller('date')

In [264]: flam = lambda x: x.date()

In [265]: fmeth = Timestamp.date

In [266]: s2 = Series(date_range('20010101', periods=1000000, freq='T'))

In [267]: s2
Out[267]:
0    2001-01-01 00:00:00
1    2001-01-01 00:01:00
2    2001-01-01 00:02:00
3    2001-01-01 00:03:00
4    2001-01-01 00:04:00
5    2001-01-01 00:05:00
6    2001-01-01 00:06:00
7    2001-01-01 00:07:00
8    2001-01-01 00:08:00
9    2001-01-01 00:09:00
10   2001-01-01 00:10:00
11   2001-01-01 00:11:00
12   2001-01-01 00:12:00
13   2001-01-01 00:13:00
14   2001-01-01 00:14:00
...
999985   2002-11-26 10:25:00
999986   2002-11-26 10:26:00
999987   2002-11-26 10:27:00
999988   2002-11-26 10:28:00
999989   2002-11-26 10:29:00
999990   2002-11-26 10:30:00
999991   2002-11-26 10:31:00
999992   2002-11-26 10:32:00
999993   2002-11-26 10:33:00
999994   2002-11-26 10:34:00
999995   2002-11-26 10:35:00
999996   2002-11-26 10:36:00
999997   2002-11-26 10:37:00
999998   2002-11-26 10:38:00
999999   2002-11-26 10:39:00
Length: 1000000, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [269]: timeit s2.map(f)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.04 s per loop

In [270]: timeit s2.map(flam)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.1 s per loop

In [271]: timeit s2.map(fmeth)
1 loops, best of 3: 968 ms per loop
```

Keep in mind that one of the goals of `pandas` is to provide a layer on top of `numpy` so that (most of the time) you don't have to deal with the low level details of the `ndarray`. So getting the raw `datetime.date` objects in an array is of limited use since they don't correspond to any `numpy.dtype` that is supported by `pandas` (`pandas` only supports `datetime64[ns]` [that's nanoseconds] dtypes). That said, sometimes you need to do this.

Comment: thanks so much for the comprehensive answer! FWIW, I noticed that `s.map(methodcaller('date'))` seems to be the fastest of the three options given here.

Comment: @blaklaybul Good to know. I'll put up some `timeit`s.

Comment: @blaklaybul I've added another way to do this using the unbound `Timestamp.date` method. It's the fastest.

Comment: Just for beauty: the 's' creation is a bit less typing with `s=Series(date_range(Timestamp('now'), periods=2))`

Comment: I believe that @Phillip's intention was create a big series so that he could test the efficiency of each of his methods using ipython's timeout magic.

Comment: Sure, but I was referring to the very first creation of s. By the way, to follow up Phillip's last part about the datetime index's `date` member:That means, that `Series(DatetimeIndex(s).date)` is another solution.

Comment: O yes sorry about that, you're totally correct. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this only came in recently, but there are built-in methods for this.  Try:

```
In [27]: s = pd.Series(pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('now'), periods=2))
In [28]: s
Out[28]: 
0   2016-02-11 19:11:43.386016
1   2016-02-12 19:11:43.386016
dtype: datetime64[ns]
In [29]: s.dt.to_pydatetime()
Out[29]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 11, 19, 11, 43, 386016),
   datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 12, 19, 11, 43, 386016)], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `.dt.date` on `datetime64[ns]` of the `dataframe`.

For e.g. `df['Created_date'] = df['Created_date'].dt.date`

Input `dataframe` named as `test_df`:

```
print(test_df)
```

Result:

```
         Created_date
0     2015-03-04 15:39:16
1     2015-03-22 17:36:49
2     2015-03-25 22:08:45
3     2015-03-16 13:45:20
4     2015-03-19 18:53:50
```

Checking `dtypes`:

```
print(test_df.dtypes)
```

Result:

```
Created_date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Extracting `date` and updating `Created_date` column:

```
test_df['Created_date'] = test_df['Created_date'].dt.date
print(test_df)
```

Result:

```
  Created_date
0   2015-03-04
1   2015-03-22
2   2015-03-25
3   2015-03-16
4   2015-03-19
```

Answer (score 1):

well I would do this way.

```
pdTime =pd.date_range(timeStamp, periods=len(years), freq="D")
pdTime[i].strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```