# date_range not accepting the variable I want to use?

Tags: python, pandas

When I input a value like '2015-08', my date_range works as intended. If I use the startdate variable, then it no longer works? I cannot figure out why this would be.

The error I get is "Cannot convert input to Timestamp"

Comment: Aren't you trying to pass a Series when the function signature accepts a string or datetime-like value: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html

Comment: I was using this post as a reference where I saw the series (to use .map)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105976/get-mm-dd-yyyy-from-pandas-timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not for points.** I'm a bit confused, isn't what you're doing just basically the following?

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
print now.strftime("%Y-%m")
month_ago = now.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days = 1)
print month_ago.strftime("%Y-%m")
months_ago = month_ago.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days = 1)
print months_ago.strftime("%Y-%m")
```

Output:

```
2015-11
2015-10
2015-09
```

The above might not be the perfect answer, but you can substitute any `datetime` for `now` and it will give you basically the current and last two months. Adjust as needed, of course.

**EDIT:**

You can even take it  a step further and just create a function that allows you to specify the numbers of months back or use a custom date.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def last_n_months(num_of_months, start_date=datetime.now(), include_curr=True):
    f = "%Y-%m"
    curr = start_date
    if include_curr:
        yield curr.strftime(f)
    for num in range(num_of_months):
        curr = curr.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
        yield curr.strftime(f)

# This month and last 12 months.
print [m for m in last_n_months(12)]
# ['2015-11', '2015-10', '2015-09', '2015-08', '2015-07', '2015-06', '2015-05', '2015-04', '2015-03', '2015-02', '2015-01', '2014-12', '2014-11']

# Last 12 months only.
print [m for m in last_n_months(12, include_curr=False)]
# ['2015-10', '2015-09', '2015-08', '2015-07', '2015-06', '2015-05', '2015-04', '2015-03', '2015-02', '2015-01', '2014-12', '2014-11']    

# Last 12 months from custom date, exclude custom date.
d = datetime(2012, 6, 1)
print [m for m in last_n_months(12, d, False)]
# ['2012-05', '2012-04', '2012-03', '2012-02', '2012-01', '2011-12', '2011-11', '2011-10', '2011-09', '2011-08', '2011-07', '2011-06']
```

Comment: This function was very helpful and did what I needed it to do. I also modified it for other reports I generate which have daily files (just got rid of the .replace part). 

Thanks a bunch