# Generate list of months between interval

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to generate a python list containing all months occurring between two dates, with the input and output formatted as follows:

```
date1 = "2014-10-10"  # input start date
date2 = "2016-01-07"  # input end date
month_list = ['Oct-14', 'Nov-14', 'Dec-14', 'Jan-15', 'Feb-15', 'Mar-15', 'Apr-15', 'May-15', 'Jun-15', 'Jul-15', 'Aug-15', 'Sep-15', 'Oct-15', 'Nov-15', 'Dec-15', 'Jan-16']  # output
```

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921513) for an idea. You can modify the function there to suit your needs.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dates = ["2014-10-10", "2016-01-07"]
>>> start, end = [datetime.strptime(_, "%Y-%m-%d") for _ in dates]
>>> OrderedDict(((start + timedelta(_)).strftime(r"%b-%y"), None) for _ in xrange((end - start).days)).keys()
['Oct-14', 'Nov-14', 'Dec-14', 'Jan-15', 'Feb-15', 'Mar-15', 'Apr-15', 'May-15', 'Jun-15', 'Jul-15', 'Aug-15', 'Sep-15', 'Oct-15', 'Nov-15', 'Dec-15', 'Jan-16']
```

**Update:** a bit of explanation, as requested in one comment. There are three problems here: parsing the dates into appropriate data structures (`strptime`); getting the date range given the two extremes and the step (one month); formatting the output dates (`strftime`). The `datetime` type overloads the subtraction operator, so that `end - start` makes sense. The result is a `timedelta` object that represents the difference between the two dates, and the `.days` attribute gets this difference expressed in days. There is no `.months` attribute, so we iterate one day at a time and convert the dates to the desired output format. This yields a lot of duplicates, which the `OrderedDict` removes while keeping the items in the right order.

Now this is simple and concise because it lets the datetime module do all the work, but it's also horribly inefficient.  We're calling a lot of methods for each day while we only need to output months.  If performance is not an issue, the above code will be just fine.  Otherwise, we'll have to work a bit more. Let's compare the above implementation with a more efficient one:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import OrderedDict

dates = ["2014-10-10", "2016-01-07"]

def monthlist_short(dates):
    start, end = [datetime.strptime(_, "%Y-%m-%d") for _ in dates]
    return OrderedDict(((start + timedelta(_)).strftime(r"%b-%y"), None) for _ in xrange((end - start).days)).keys()

def monthlist_fast(dates):
    start, end = [datetime.strptime(_, "%Y-%m-%d") for _ in dates]
    total_months = lambda dt: dt.month + 12 * dt.year
    mlist = []
    for tot_m in xrange(total_months(start)-1, total_months(end)):
        y, m = divmod(tot_m, 12)
        mlist.append(datetime(y, m+1, 1).strftime("%b-%y"))
    return mlist

assert monthlist_fast(dates) == monthlist_short(dates)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from timeit import Timer
    for func in "monthlist_short", "monthlist_fast":
        print func, Timer("%s(dates)" % func, "from __main__ import dates, %s" % func).timeit(1000)
```

On my laptop, I get the following output:

```
monthlist_short 2.3209939003
monthlist_fast 0.0774540901184
```

The concise implementation is about 30 times slower, so I would not recommend it in time-critical applications :)

Comment: Note that using Python 3 you should use `range()` instead of `xrange()`. You'll also need to call `list()` on the result (which is an `odict_keys()`) if you want a list.

Answer (score 174):

I found a very succinct way to do this with Pandas, sharing in case it helps anybody:

---

**UPDATE:** I've got it down to a one-liner with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890391/how-to-include-end-date-in-pandas-date-range-method) :)

```
pd.date_range('2014-10-10','2016-01-07', 
              freq='MS').strftime("%b-%y").tolist()
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

```
daterange = pd.date_range('2014-10-10','2016-01-07' , freq='1M') 
daterange = daterange.union([daterange[-1] + 1])  
daterange = [d.strftime('%b-%y') for d in daterange]
```

The second line prevents the last date from getting clipped off the list.

Comment: I'm realizing the updated version is quite similar to answer by tmsss...see below.

Comment: Its not returning start date. eg: `pd.date_range('2021-10-2','2021-12-30', freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%b").tolist()` then output is `['2021-Nov', '2021-Dec']`. But its suppose to be `['Oct-21', 'Nov-21', 'Dec-21']`

Comment: Yeah, the one-liner does not actually provide the desired output.

Comment: oh yes, sorry -- it was just a date formatter issue, I've fixed it now.

Comment: `freq=MS` means Month Start (`ME` = Month End) for anyone wondering

Answer (score 18):

With pandas, you can have a one liner like this:

```
import pandas as pd

date1 = "2014-10-10"  # input start date
date2 = "2016-01-07"  # input end date

month_list = [i.strftime("%b-%y") for i in pd.date_range(start=date1, end=date2, freq='MS')]
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to use [Calendar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#module-calendar) and [Datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

```
import calendar
from datetime import *

date1 = datetime.strptime("2014-10-10", "%Y-%m-%d")
date2 = datetime.strptime("2016-01-07", "%Y-%m-%d")
date1 = date1.replace(day = 1)
date2 = date2.replace(day = 1)

months_str = calendar.month_name
months = []

while date1 < date2:
    month = date1.month
    year  = date1.year

    month_str = months_str[month][0:3]
    months.append("{0}-{1}".format(month_str, str(year)[-2:]))

    next_month = month + 1 if month != 12 else 1
    next_year = year + 1 if next_month == 1 else year
    date1 = date1.replace(month = next_month, year = next_year)

print months
```

This code returns

```
['Oct-14', 'Nov-14', 'Dec-14', 'Jan-14', 'Feb-15', 'Mar-15', 'Apr-15', 'May-15', 'Jun-15', 'Jul-15', 'Aug-15', 'Sep-15', 'Oct-15', 'Nov-15', 'Dec-15', 'Jan-15']
```

Comment: I get this by running your code: ['Oct-1', 'Nov-1', 'Dec-1', 'Jan-1', 'Feb-1', 'Mar-1', 'Apr-1', 'May-1', 'Jun-1', 'Jul-1', 'Aug-1', 'Sep-1', 'Oct-1', 'Nov-1', 'Dec-1', 'Jan-1']

Comment: yes!! It was a little mistake.. I wrote `str(year)[-2]` instead of `str(year)[-2:]`. Fixed! :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution with a simple list comprehension which uses `range` to know where months must start and end

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
sd = dt.strptime('2014-10-10', "%Y-%m-%d") 
ed = dt.strptime('2016-01-07', "%Y-%m-%d") 

lst = [dt.strptime('%2.2d-%2.2d' % (y, m), '%Y-%m').strftime('%b-%y') \
       for y in xrange(sd.year, ed.year+1) \
       for m in xrange(sd.month if y==sd.year else 1, ed.month+1 if y == ed.year else 13)]

print lst
```

produces

```
['Oct-14', 'Nov-14', 'Dec-14', 'Jan-15', 'Feb-15', 'Mar-15', 'Apr-15', 'May-15', 'Jun-15', 'Jul-15', 'Aug-15', 'Sep-15', 'Oct-15', 'Nov-15', 'Dec-15', 'Jan-16']
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in keeping your dates in a Python format, you can try using `to_pydatetime()`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

datemin = datetime(2010, 1, 1)
datemax = datetime(2019, 12, 31)

# First day of month
pd.date_range(datemin, datemax, freq='MS').to_pydatetime().tolist()

# Last day of month
pd.date_range(datemin, datemax, freq='M').to_pydatetime().tolist()
```

[List of Offset Aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases)

Answer (score 1):

Having done similar stuff previously, I took a stab at solving this. Using distinct components for doing this is more flexible and enables you to mix and match them for different use-cases. They also can be tested more easily this way, as you can see by the doctests in `iterate_months`.

Also I suggest to use `datetime.date` objects for your input as you can just do more with those. To do that you'll have to first parse your input string, but this is very easily done.

Parsing the date-strings

```
def datify(date):
    if isinstance(date, datetime.date):
        return date
    elif isinstance(date, datetime.datetime):
        return date.date()
    else:
        # taken from simleo's answer
        return datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

### First, we iterate through the months

```
import datetime


def iterate_months(start_date, end_date):
    """Iterate monthly between two given dates.

    Emitted will be the first day of each month.

    >>> list(iterate_months(datetime.date(1999, 11, 1),
    ...                     datetime.date(2000, 2, 1)))
    [datetime.date(1999, 11, 1), datetime.date(1999, 12, 1),\
 datetime.date(2000, 1, 1), datetime.date(2000, 2, 1)]

    """
    assert isinstance(start_date, datetime.date)
    assert isinstance(end_date, datetime.date)
    assert start_date < end_date

    year = start_date.year
    month = start_date.month
    while True:
        current = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
        yield current
        if current.month == end_date.month and current.year == end_date.year:
            break
        else:
            month = ((month + 1) % 12) or 12
            if month == 1:
                year += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

### To format your dates, use something like this

```
def format_month(date):
    return date.strftime(r"%b-%y")
```

### Putting it all together

```
start = datify("2014-10-10")
end = datify("2016-01-07")

for entry in iterate_months(start, end):
    print format_month(entry)
```

Or save it as a list:

```
result = list(iterate_months(start, end))
```

Answer (score 1):

Find below my approach to this problem using **split** and simple **modulo-based** iterations without importing any special module.

```
date1 = "2014-10-10"
date2 = "2016-01-07"

y0 = int( date1.split('-')[0] ) # 2014
y1 = int( date2.split('-')[0] ) # 2016

m0 = int( date1.split('-')[1] ) - 1 # 10-1 --> 9 because will be used for indexing
m1 = int( date2.split('-')[1] ) - 1 # 01-1 --> 0 because will be used for indexing

months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
result = []
start = m0
for y in range(y0, y1+1):
    for m in range(start,12):
        result.append( str( months[m  % 12])+'-'+str(y) )
        if y == y1 and (m % 12) == m1:
            break
    start = 0

print result
```

**$ python dates.py**

```
['Oct-2014', 'Nov-2014', 'Dec-2014', 'Jan-2015', 'Feb-2015', 'Mar-2015', 'Apr-2015', 'May-2015', 'Jun-2015', 'Jul-2015', 'Aug-2015', 'Sep-2015', 'Oct-2015', 'Nov-2015', 'Dec-2015', 'Jan-2016']
```

Answer (score 1):

I came to a solution that uses `python-dateutil` and works with Python 3.8+:

https://gist.github.com/anatoly-scherbakov/593770d446a06f109438a134863ba969

```
def month_range(
    start: datetime.date,
    end: datetime.date,
) -> Iterator[datetime.date]:
    """Yields the 1st day of each month in the given date range."""
    yield from itertools.takewhile(
        lambda date: date < end,
        itertools.accumulate(
            itertools.repeat(relativedelta(months=1)),
            operator.add,
            initial=start,
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dictionary that contains pair of month's starting date and ending date between your desired years, then here's how to get that.

```
start_year = int(input("Enter Starting Year: "))
end_year = int(input("Enter Ending Year: "))
import calendar
month_dict = {}
for x in range(start_year, end_year):
    for y in range(1, 13):
        if y < 10:
            start_date = '01'+'-'+'0'+str(y)+'-'+str(x)
            end_date = str(calendar.monthrange(x, y)[1])+'-'+'0'+str(y)+'-'+str(x)
            month_dict[start_date] = end_date
        else:
            start_date = '01'+'-'+str(y)+'-'+str(x)
            end_date = str(calendar.monthrange(x, y)[1])+'-'+str(y)+'-'+str(x)
            month_dict[start_date] = end_date
```

This gives the following output:

```
{'01-01-2000': '31-01-2000',
 '01-02-2000': '29-02-2000',
 '01-03-2000': '31-03-2000',
 '01-04-2000': '30-04-2000',
 '01-05-2000': '31-05-2000',
 '01-06-2000': '30-06-2000',
 '01-07-2000': '31-07-2000',
 '01-08-2000': '31-08-2000',
 '01-09-2000': '30-09-2000',
 '01-10-2000': '31-10-2000',
 '01-11-2000': '30-11-2000',
 '01-12-2000': '31-12-2000',
 '01-01-2001': '31-01-2001',
 '01-02-2001': '28-02-2001',
 '01-03-2001': '31-03-2001',
 '01-04-2001': '30-04-2001',
 '01-05-2001': '31-05-2001',
 '01-06-2001': '30-06-2001',
 '01-07-2001': '31-07-2001',
 '01-08-2001': '31-08-2001',
 '01-09-2001': '30-09-2001',
 '01-10-2001': '31-10-2001',
 '01-11-2001': '30-11-2001',
 '01-12-2001': '31-12-2001',
 '01-01-2002': '31-01-2002',
 '01-02-2002': '28-02-2002',
 '01-03-2002': '31-03-2002',
 '01-04-2002': '30-04-2002',
 '01-05-2002': '31-05-2002',
 '01-06-2002': '30-06-2002',
 '01-07-2002': '31-07-2002',
 '01-08-2002': '31-08-2002',
 '01-09-2002': '30-09-2002',
 '01-10-2002': '31-10-2002',
 '01-11-2002': '30-11-2002',
 '01-12-2002': '31-12-2002',
 '01-01-2003': '31-01-2003',
 '01-02-2003': '28-02-2003',
 '01-03-2003': '31-03-2003',
 '01-04-2003': '30-04-2003',
 '01-05-2003': '31-05-2003',
 '01-06-2003': '30-06-2003',
 '01-07-2003': '31-07-2003',
 '01-08-2003': '31-08-2003',
 '01-09-2003': '30-09-2003',
 '01-10-2003': '31-10-2003',
 '01-11-2003': '30-11-2003',
 '01-12-2003': '31-12-2003',
 '01-01-2004': '31-01-2004',
 '01-02-2004': '29-02-2004',
 '01-03-2004': '31-03-2004',
 '01-04-2004': '30-04-2004',
 '01-05-2004': '31-05-2004',
 '01-06-2004': '30-06-2004',
 '01-07-2004': '31-07-2004',
 '01-08-2004': '31-08-2004',
 '01-09-2004': '30-09-2004',
 '01-10-2004': '31-10-2004',
 '01-11-2004': '30-11-2004',
 '01-12-2004': '31-12-2004',
 '01-01-2005': '31-01-2005',
 '01-02-2005': '28-02-2005',
 '01-03-2005': '31-03-2005',
 '01-04-2005': '30-04-2005',
 '01-05-2005': '31-05-2005',
 '01-06-2005': '30-06-2005',
 '01-07-2005': '31-07-2005',
 '01-08-2005': '31-08-2005',
 '01-09-2005': '30-09-2005',
 '01-10-2005': '31-10-2005',
 '01-11-2005': '30-11-2005',
 '01-12-2005': '31-12-2005',
 '01-01-2006': '31-01-2006',
 '01-02-2006': '28-02-2006',
 '01-03-2006': '31-03-2006',
 '01-04-2006': '30-04-2006',
 '01-05-2006': '31-05-2006',
 '01-06-2006': '30-06-2006',
 '01-07-2006': '31-07-2006',
 '01-08-2006': '31-08-2006',
 '01-09-2006': '30-09-2006',
 '01-10-2006': '31-10-2006',
 '01-11-2006': '30-11-2006',
 '01-12-2006': '31-12-2006',
 '01-01-2007': '31-01-2007',
 '01-02-2007': '28-02-2007',
 '01-03-2007': '31-03-2007',
 '01-04-2007': '30-04-2007',
 '01-05-2007': '31-05-2007',
 '01-06-2007': '30-06-2007',
 '01-07-2007': '31-07-2007',
 '01-08-2007': '31-08-2007',
 '01-09-2007': '30-09-2007',
 '01-10-2007': '31-10-2007',
 '01-11-2007': '30-11-2007',
 '01-12-2007': '31-12-2007',
 '01-01-2008': '31-01-2008',
 '01-02-2008': '29-02-2008',
 '01-03-2008': '31-03-2008',
 '01-04-2008': '30-04-2008',
 '01-05-2008': '31-05-2008',
 '01-06-2008': '30-06-2008',
 '01-07-2008': '31-07-2008',
 '01-08-2008': '31-08-2008',
 '01-09-2008': '30-09-2008',
 '01-10-2008': '31-10-2008',
 '01-11-2008': '30-11-2008',
 '01-12-2008': '31-12-2008',
 '01-01-2009': '31-01-2009',
 '01-02-2009': '28-02-2009',
 '01-03-2009': '31-03-2009',
 '01-04-2009': '30-04-2009',
 '01-05-2009': '31-05-2009',
 '01-06-2009': '30-06-2009',
 '01-07-2009': '31-07-2009',
 '01-08-2009': '31-08-2009',
 '01-09-2009': '30-09-2009',
 '01-10-2009': '31-10-2009',
 '01-11-2009': '30-11-2009',
 '01-12-2009': '31-12-2009',
 '01-01-2010': '31-01-2010',
 '01-02-2010': '28-02-2010',
 '01-03-2010': '31-03-2010',
 '01-04-2010': '30-04-2010',
 '01-05-2010': '31-05-2010',
 '01-06-2010': '30-06-2010',
 '01-07-2010': '31-07-2010',
 '01-08-2010': '31-08-2010',
 '01-09-2010': '30-09-2010',
 '01-10-2010': '31-10-2010',
 '01-11-2010': '30-11-2010',
 '01-12-2010': '31-12-2010',
 '01-01-2011': '31-01-2011',
 '01-02-2011': '28-02-2011',
 '01-03-2011': '31-03-2011',
 '01-04-2011': '30-04-2011',
 '01-05-2011': '31-05-2011',
 '01-06-2011': '30-06-2011',
 '01-07-2011': '31-07-2011',
 '01-08-2011': '31-08-2011',
 '01-09-2011': '30-09-2011',
 '01-10-2011': '31-10-2011',
 '01-11-2011': '30-11-2011',
 '01-12-2011': '31-12-2011',
 '01-01-2012': '31-01-2012',
 '01-02-2012': '29-02-2012',
 '01-03-2012': '31-03-2012',
 '01-04-2012': '30-04-2012',
 '01-05-2012': '31-05-2012',
 '01-06-2012': '30-06-2012',
 '01-07-2012': '31-07-2012',
 '01-08-2012': '31-08-2012',
 '01-09-2012': '30-09-2012',
 '01-10-2012': '31-10-2012',
 '01-11-2012': '30-11-2012',
 '01-12-2012': '31-12-2012',
 '01-01-2013': '31-01-2013',
 '01-02-2013': '28-02-2013',
 '01-03-2013': '31-03-2013',
 '01-04-2013': '30-04-2013',
 '01-05-2013': '31-05-2013',
 '01-06-2013': '30-06-2013',
 '01-07-2013': '31-07-2013',
 '01-08-2013': '31-08-2013',
 '01-09-2013': '30-09-2013',
 '01-10-2013': '31-10-2013',
 '01-11-2013': '30-11-2013',
 '01-12-2013': '31-12-2013',
 '01-01-2014': '31-01-2014',
 '01-02-2014': '28-02-2014',
 '01-03-2014': '31-03-2014',
 '01-04-2014': '30-04-2014',
 '01-05-2014': '31-05-2014',
 '01-06-2014': '30-06-2014',
 '01-07-2014': '31-07-2014',
 '01-08-2014': '31-08-2014',
 '01-09-2014': '30-09-2014',
 '01-10-2014': '31-10-2014',
 '01-11-2014': '30-11-2014',
 '01-12-2014': '31-12-2014',
 '01-01-2015': '31-01-2015',
 '01-02-2015': '28-02-2015',
 '01-03-2015': '31-03-2015',
 '01-04-2015': '30-04-2015',
 '01-05-2015': '31-05-2015',
 '01-06-2015': '30-06-2015',
 '01-07-2015': '31-07-2015',
 '01-08-2015': '31-08-2015',
 '01-09-2015': '30-09-2015',
 '01-10-2015': '31-10-2015',
 '01-11-2015': '30-11-2015',
 '01-12-2015': '31-12-2015',
 '01-01-2016': '31-01-2016',
 '01-02-2016': '29-02-2016',
 '01-03-2016': '31-03-2016',
 '01-04-2016': '30-04-2016',
 '01-05-2016': '31-05-2016',
 '01-06-2016': '30-06-2016',
 '01-07-2016': '31-07-2016',
 '01-08-2016': '31-08-2016',
 '01-09-2016': '30-09-2016',
 '01-10-2016': '31-10-2016',
 '01-11-2016': '30-11-2016',
 '01-12-2016': '31-12-2016',
 '01-01-2017': '31-01-2017',
 '01-02-2017': '28-02-2017',
 '01-03-2017': '31-03-2017',
 '01-04-2017': '30-04-2017',
 '01-05-2017': '31-05-2017',
 '01-06-2017': '30-06-2017',
 '01-07-2017': '31-07-2017',
 '01-08-2017': '31-08-2017',
 '01-09-2017': '30-09-2017',
 '01-10-2017': '31-10-2017',
 '01-11-2017': '30-11-2017',
 '01-12-2017': '31-12-2017',
 '01-01-2018': '31-01-2018',
 '01-02-2018': '28-02-2018',
 '01-03-2018': '31-03-2018',
 '01-04-2018': '30-04-2018',
 '01-05-2018': '31-05-2018',
 '01-06-2018': '30-06-2018',
 '01-07-2018': '31-07-2018',
 '01-08-2018': '31-08-2018',
 '01-09-2018': '30-09-2018',
 '01-10-2018': '31-10-2018',
 '01-11-2018': '30-11-2018',
 '01-12-2018': '31-12-2018',
 '01-01-2019': '31-01-2019',
 '01-02-2019': '28-02-2019',
 '01-03-2019': '31-03-2019',
 '01-04-2019': '30-04-2019',
 '01-05-2019': '31-05-2019',
 '01-06-2019': '30-06-2019',
 '01-07-2019': '31-07-2019',
 '01-08-2019': '31-08-2019',
 '01-09-2019': '30-09-2019',
 '01-10-2019': '31-10-2019',
 '01-11-2019': '30-11-2019',
 '01-12-2019': '31-12-2019',
 '01-01-2020': '31-01-2020',
 '01-02-2020': '29-02-2020',
 '01-03-2020': '31-03-2020',
 '01-04-2020': '30-04-2020',
 '01-05-2020': '31-05-2020',
 '01-06-2020': '30-06-2020',
 '01-07-2020': '31-07-2020',
 '01-08-2020': '31-08-2020',
 '01-09-2020': '30-09-2020',
 '01-10-2020': '31-10-2020',
 '01-11-2020': '30-11-2020',
 '01-12-2020': '31-12-2020',
 '01-01-2021': '31-01-2021',
 '01-02-2021': '28-02-2021',
 '01-03-2021': '31-03-2021',
 '01-04-2021': '30-04-2021',
 '01-05-2021': '31-05-2021',
 '01-06-2021': '30-06-2021',
 '01-07-2021': '31-07-2021',
 '01-08-2021': '31-08-2021',
 '01-09-2021': '30-09-2021',
 '01-10-2021': '31-10-2021',
 '01-11-2021': '30-11-2021',
 '01-12-2021': '31-12-2021'}
```

Comment: So useful, but surely there is an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

here is the similar version of what Pynchia suggestioned, the below implementation is for python 3.8 the one he implemented is for python 2.x

```
import datetime
st="2020-06-24"
ed="2020-11-24"
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(st.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(ed.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d')

months = [datetime.datetime.strptime('%2.2d-%2.2d' % (y, m), '%Y-%m').strftime('%b-%y')
    for y in range(start_date.year, end_date.year + 1)
    for m in range(start_date.month if y == start_date.year else 1, end_date.month + 1 if y == end_date.year else 13)]

print(months)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it will list down all the month from start to end as a continuous chain starting from the start date.

```
import datetime
a='2021-12-1'
b='2022-1-2'
d1=datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d')
d2=datetime.datetime.strptime(b,'%Y-%m-%d')
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

totalmonts=(d2.year-d1.year)*12+d2.month-11+12-d1.month
print(totalmonts)
for i in range(totalmonts):
    print(months[(d1.month+i-1)%12])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using [Calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) and [Datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) libraries.

```py
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# set start and end dates
start_month = datetime.strptime("2022-12", "%Y-%m")
end_month = datetime.now()

# loop and print all in between months
months_list = list()
current_month = start_month
while current_month < end_month:
    # append current month
    months_list.append(
        f"{calendar.month_name[current_month.month][:3]}-{current_month.strftime('%y')}"
    )

    # increment current month by adding 33 days to 'current_month'
    current_month += timedelta(days=33)

    # reset day to starting day (i.e. 1st day of the month)
    current_month = current_month.replace(day=1)
print(months_list)
```

The output looks like this:

```bash
['Dec-22', 'Jan-23', 'Feb-23', 'Mar-23', 'Apr-23', 'May-23', 'Jun-23', 'Jul-23']
```

Answer (score -1):

I just joined so don't have enough to comment on [atkat12's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42857552/22394542), but if you are like me and found that their answer seems to miss the first or last month, it's because they use a frequency of `MS`:

```
>>> pandas.date_range("2023-01-25","2023-08-12",freq="MS").strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
['2023-02-01', '2023-03-01', '2023-04-01', '2023-05-01', '2023-06-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-08-01']

>>> pandas.date_range("2023-01-25","2023-08-12",freq="M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
['2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31', '2023-04-30', '2023-05-31', '2023-06-30', '2023-07-31']
>>>
```

`M` means use the first day of the month, whereas `MS` means use the last day.
[See the docs here for more information](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases).

Based on this however, I found you can make a slightly hacky workaround which gets all months:

```
>>> pandas.date_range("2023-01-25","2023-08-12",freq="1D").strftime("%Y %B").drop_duplicates().tolist()
['2023 January', '2023 February', '2023 March', '2023 April', '2023 May', '2023 June', '2023 July', '2023 August']
```

This basically sets the frequency to a day, converts it into the desired monthly output and removes any duplicates. I intially tried this with `set(list(...))` but then you end up with things being ordered alphabetically rather than chronologically.

Comment: I'm voting to delete this, because it's the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42857552/7758804) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367595/7758804). Don't add **thank you**, duplicate, or **confirmation** answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) from quality contributions, you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.