# How to include end date in pandas date_range method?

Tags: python, string, datetime, pandas, range

From `pd.date_range('2016-01', '2016-05', freq='M', ).strftime('%Y-%m')`,  the last month is `2016-04`, but I was expecting it to be `2016-05`. It seems to me this function is behaving like the `range` method, where the end parameter is not included in the returning array.

Is there a way to get the end month included in the returning array, without processing the string for the end month?

Comment: `date_range()` parameters still seems to be a bit tricky https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16354

Comment: I believe this is the best answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75663045/9439097

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A way to do it without messing with figuring out month ends yourself.

```
pd.date_range(*(pd.to_datetime(['2016-01', '2016-05']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()), freq='M')

DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-31', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-30',
           '2016-05-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Comment: With this solution I don't need to mess with days and (n+1) month.

Comment: This excludes the first month though if in some cases... `pd.date_range(*(pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-31', '2016-05']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()), freq='M')` returns `DatetimeIndex(['2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-30', '2016-05-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')`

Comment: On the other hand, this one works correctly for my situation: `pd.date_range('2016-01-31', pd.to_datetime('2016-05') + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(), freq='M')`

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.union.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.union) to add the next logical value after initializing the `date_range`.  It should work as written for any frequency:

```
d = pd.date_range('2016-01', '2016-05', freq='M')
d = d.union([d[-1] + 1]).strftime('%Y-%m')
```

Alternatively, you can use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.period_range.html) instead of `date_range`.  Depending on what you intend to do, this might not be the right thing to use, but it satisfies your question:

```
pd.period_range('2016-01', '2016-05', freq='M').strftime('%Y-%m')
```

In either case, the resulting output is as expected:

```
['2016-01' '2016-02' '2016-03' '2016-04' '2016-05']
```

Comment: Thanks for period_range, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: `.union` is also solution to a similar problem: you want monthly intervals, including your endpoints, but your start and end do not fall on the beginning/end of the month, eg `start=pd.to_datetime('2016-01-05')`, `finish=pd.to_datetime('2016-05-13')`, `d=date_range(start, finish,freq='M').union([start, finish])`.  It even sorts the index for you.

Comment: getting this error now: TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

Comment: @Rafael got that error too, easy (and better readable IMO) workaround is `pd.date_range('2016-01', '2016-05', freq='M').strftime('%Y-%m').union(['2016-05'])`

Answer (score 12):

For the later crowd. You can also try to use the Month-Start frequency.

```
>>> pd.date_range('2016-01', '2016-05', freq='MS', format = "%Y-%m" )
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01',
               '2016-05-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

Comment: works great with pandas 1.3.4 except the format argument which needed to be replaced by `.strftime('%Y-%m')`

Answer (score 1):

Include the day when specifying the dates in `date_range` call

```
pd.date_range('2016-01-31', '2016-05-31', freq='M', ).strftime('%Y-%m')

array(['2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-03', '2016-04', '2016-05'], 
      dtype='|S7')
```

Comment: If you add a day manually, then you might as well just add one more month dont you think

Comment: No.  I can imagine a need and reason for preferring either depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using datetime objects in dataframe. I would set the boundaries through .min() and .max() functions and then fill in missing dates using the pd.date_range function. Unfortunately the returned list/df was missing the maximum value.

I found two work arounds for this:

1) Add "closed = None" parameter in the pd.date_range function. This worked in the example below; however, it didn't work for me when working only with dataframes (no idea why).

2) If option #1 doesn't work then you can add one extra unit (in this case a day) using the datetime.timedelta() function. In the case below it over indexed by a day but it can work for you if the date_range function isn't giving you the full range.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt 

#List of dates as strings
time_series = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-5', '2020-01-6', '2020-01-7']

#Creates dataframe with time data that is converted to datetime object 
raw_data_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(time_series), columns = ['Raw_Time_Series'])

#Creates an indexed_time list that includes missing dates and the full time range

#Option No. 1 is to use the closed = None parameter choice. 
indexed_time = pd.date_range(start = raw_data_df.Raw_Time_Series.min(),end = raw_data_df.Raw_Time_Series.max(),freq='D',closed= None)
print('indexed_time option #! = ', indexed_time)

#Option No. 2 if the function allows you to extend the time by one unit (in this case day) 
#by using the datetime.timedelta function to get what you need. 
indexed_time = pd.date_range(start = raw_data_df.Raw_Time_Series.min(),end = raw_data_df.Raw_Time_Series.max()+dt.timedelta(days=1),freq='D')
print('indexed_time option #2 = ', indexed_time)

#In this case you over index by an extra day because the date_range function works properly
#However, if the "closed = none" parameters doesn't extend through the full range then this is a good work around
```

Answer (score 1):

```
start_date = '2021-09-10'
end_date = '2021-12-15'

value = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='M').union(pd.date_range(end=end_date, periods=1))
DatetimeIndex(['2021-09-30', '2021-10-31', '2021-11-30', '2021-12-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. **You need to add the (n+1) boundary**

```
   pd.date_range('2016-01', '2016-06', freq='M' ).strftime('%Y-%m')
```

> The start and end dates are strictly inclusive. So it will not
>   generate any dates outside of those dates if specified.
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

Either way, you have to manually add some information. I believe adding just one more month is not a lot of work.

Comment: This quote from the docs holds true when `freq='D'`, when is monthly it doesn't hold for the end date tough.

Comment: ok. it does not change the fact that you need to add your boundary :)

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for this issue is that the function `pd.to_datetime()` converts a `'%Y-%m'` date string by default to the first of the month datetime, or `'%Y-%m-01'`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('2016-05')
Timestamp('2016-05-01 00:00:00')
>>> pd.date_range('2016-01', '2016-02')
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03', '2016-01-04',
               '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07', '2016-01-08',
               '2016-01-09', '2016-01-10', '2016-01-11', '2016-01-12',
               '2016-01-13', '2016-01-14', '2016-01-15', '2016-01-16',
               '2016-01-17', '2016-01-18', '2016-01-19', '2016-01-20',
               '2016-01-21', '2016-01-22', '2016-01-23', '2016-01-24',
               '2016-01-25', '2016-01-26', '2016-01-27', '2016-01-28',
               '2016-01-29', '2016-01-30', '2016-01-31', '2016-02-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Then everything follows from that. Specifying `freq='M'` includes month ends between 2016-01-01 and 2016-05-01, which is the list you receive and excludes 2016-05-31. But specifying month starts `'MS'` like the second answer provides, includes 2016-05-01 as it falls within the range. `pd.date_range()` default behavior isn't like the `range` method since ends are included. From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

> *closed* controls whether to include start and end that are on the boundary. The default includes boundary points on either end.

Answer (score 0):

Use the explicit last dates pd.date_range(2016-01-31,2016-06-30, freq='M').