# How to include both ends of a pandas date_range()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

From a pair of dates, I would like to create a list of dates at monthly frequency, including the months of both dates indicated.

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Option 1
pd.date_range(datetime(2022, 1, 13),datetime(2022, 4, 5), freq='M', inclusive='both')
# Option 2
pd.date_range("2022-01-13", "2022-04-05", freq='M', inclusive='both')
```

both return the list: `DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')`. However, I am expecting the outcome with a list of dates (4 long) with one date for each month: `[january, february, mars, april]`

If now we run:

```py
pd.date_range("2022-01-13", "2022-04-05", freq='M', inclusive='right')
```

we still obtain the same result as before. It looks like `inclusive` has no effect on the outcome.

Pandas version. 1.5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### using [`MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html) and [`Day`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.Day.html) offsets

This is because 2022-04-05 is **before** your month end (2022-04-30).

You can use:

```
pd.date_range("2022-01-13", pd.Timestamp("2022-04-05")+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(),
              freq='M', inclusive='both')
```

A more robust variant to also handle the case in which the input date is already the month end:

```
pd.date_range("2022-01-13",
              pd.Timestamp("2022-04-05")-pd.offsets.Day()+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(),
              freq='M', inclusive='both')
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

##### alternative: using [`Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html)

```
pd.date_range(pd.Period('2022-01-13', 'M').to_timestamp(),
              pd.Period('2022-04-30', 'M').to_timestamp(how='end'),
              freq='M', inclusive='both')
```

Intermediates:

```
pd.Period('2022-01-13', 'M').to_timestamp()
# Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00')

pd.Period('2022-04-30', 'M').to_timestamp(how='end')
# Timestamp('2022-04-30 23:59:59.999999999')
```

##### or as periods: [`period_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html)

```
pd.period_range('2022-01-13', '2022-04-30', freq='M')
```

Output:

```
PeriodIndex(['2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03', '2022-04'], dtype='period[M]')
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway! this solves it. I did not know about `pd.offsets.MonthEnd()`

Comment: @Simon be careful if the input value is already the month end, this will jump to the next month. A trick might be to use `pd.date_range("2022-01-13", pd.Timestamp("2022-04-05")-pd.offsets.Day()+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(), freq='M', inclusive='both')`

Comment: I added another approach with periods

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `Month` definition, if you use `Day` you see the difference.
When you count in months there is no effect.

For inclusive :

`both` : a <= x <= b  (in math convention : `[a, b]`)

`neither` : a < x < b  (in math convention : `]a, b[`)

`right` : a < x <= b  (in math convention : `]a, b]`)

`left` : a <= x < b  (in math convention : `[a, b[`)

`You can't include beyond the limits`