# Print all period in between two periods in Python

Tags: python

Suppose my periods are `NOV-2016` and `MAR-2018` and I need to print all periods in between like `(NOV-2016, DEC-2016, JAN-2017` up to `MAR-2018)`. What can be done to get the desired result. For now i did this but I am not getting the desired result:

```
start_period = 'NOV-2017'
end_period = 'JUN-2019'
array = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']
year1 = int(start_period.split('-')[1])
year2 = int(end_period.split('-')[1])
diff = year2-year1
month_start = start_period.split('-')[0]
month_end = end_period.split('-')[0]
index1 = array.index(month_start)
index2 = array.index(month_end)
while diff>0:
    while(diff>=1 and (index2+1) != index1):
        if(index1==12):
            index1 = 0
        print(array[index1])
        index1+=1
    diff-=1
    if diff==0:
        break
```

Comment: And what is the result you are getting?

Comment: NOV
DEC
JAN
FEB
MAR
APR
MAY
JUN

Comment: But I should also get another output from JUL back to JUN for year 2018 and 2019

Comment: Change `diff>0` to `diff>=0`. Because you also want to treat the case where the periods are the same year.

Comment: But that wont change the output in current case no?

Comment: check this port here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898525/generate-list-of-months-between-interval-in-python/34899127

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to handle your problems if you iterate over every year. Reset the month to *JAN* at the end of every year. Check each year if you are in the final one, and then set the appropriate end month.

Here is an example:

```
start_period = 'NOV-2017'
end_period = 'JUN-2019'
months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']

def printTimePeriods(start, end):
    start_month, start_year = start.split("-")
    end_month, end_year = end.split("-")
    # Cast year to int
    start_year, end_year = int(start_year), int(end_year)

    # For every year
    for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
        month_index = 12
        # Check if we are in the last year
        if year == end_year:
            month_index = months.index(end_month) + 1
        # For every month print the period
        for month in range(months.index(start_month), month_index):
            print months[month], year
        # New year
        start_month = "JAN"

printTimePeriods(start_period, end_period)
```