# Pandas - Datetime Manipulations Not Using Apply or Map

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

You can convert pandas' datetime objects pretty easily using apply() on a column, but the issue I'm running into is that it is really slow.

I'm trying to develop another solution, but I keep running into a performance wall.

My current solution is:

```
def modify_date2(x):
    """
    applies datetime mask 1 of MM YYYY to the data
    Example: 01 2016
    """
    try:
        if pd.isnull(x) == False:
            return x.strftime('%m %Y')
        else:
            return pd.NaT
    except:
        return pd.NaT
df['columnname'] = df['columnname'].apply(modify_date2)
```

For roughly 700K records it is take 3 minutes and this is just a sub-set of my production dataset which is 23+ million records.  You see my concern.

I was trying this out:

```
df.ix[pd.notnull(df['sourcedt']), "sourcedt"] = \
datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(df['sourcedt'].dt.timetuple()))
```

But I can't do the low level conversion on the 'Series' according to the error message I am getting.  The query works fine, I can use pd.notnull() without an issue, but the setting of the value is my problem.

Any ideas on how I can speed things up?
My source data is being loaded using the pd.DataFrame.from_records().

I am using Pandas 0.16.1, Python 2.7.10

Thank you

Comment: I think the following should work: `df['columnname'] = pd.to_datetime(df['columnname'], format='%m %Y', errors='force')` not sure when the `errors` param changed but you may need to pass either `'coerce'` or `'force'`

Comment: its `errors='coerce' ` buddy

Comment: @Noobie I think in fact it's `coerce=True`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-to-datetime-and-to-timedelta, the signature changed in `0.17.0`

Comment: @EdChum it's still returning MM-DD-YYYY

Comment: I think that unless you upgrade then this will be slow [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-17-0-october-9-2015) was added in `0.17.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), dtype of `columnname` is `datetime`:

```
print (df)
  text          columnname
0    a 2016-06-13 18:00:00
1    b                 NaT
2    c 2016-07-11 19:07:00
3    d 2016-07-11 19:07:00
4    e 2016-08-01 16:00:00

print (df['columnname'].dt.strftime('%m %Y'))
0    06 2016
1        NaT
2    07 2016
3    07 2016
4    08 2016
Name: columnname, dtype: object
```

If need first convert to datetime and some dates are corrupted use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['columnname'] = pd.to_datetime(df['columnname'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%m %Y')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnname': {0: '2016-06-13 18:00', 1: np.nan, 2: 'dd', 3: '2016-07-11 19:07', 4: '2016-08-01 16:00'}, 'text': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}})
print (df)
         columnname text
0  2016-06-13 18:00    a
1               NaN    b
2                dd    c
3  2016-07-11 19:07    d
4  2016-08-01 16:00    e

df['columnname'] = pd.to_datetime(df['columnname'], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%m %Y')
print (df)
  columnname text
0    06 2016    a
1        NaT    b
2        NaT    c
3    07 2016    d
4    08 2016    e
```

Comment: this returns: Traceback (most recent call last):
  Debug Probe, prompt 72, line 1
AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: same error.  I think it's because I'm forced to use v0.16.1 not the 0.17.x version.

Comment: Is possible upgrade pandas? Last version now is `0.18.1`

Comment: [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-17-0-october-9-2015) was added in `0.17.0` so this won't work

Comment: @josh1234 - I found old solution, but it is with [`map`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19106012/2901002).

Comment: @jezrael - I can't upgrade.

Comment: @josh1234 - so unfortunately I cant help you, because then you have to use `map`, what is slow. :(

Comment: @jezrael - is map faster than apply?

Comment: @josh1234 - hard question, but I think yes. The best is test it.

Comment: @jezrael - thanks!, I figured as much.  such a shame, because except for datetime objects conversions my data manipulations are lightening fast.