# Timestamp to date conversion in Pandas 0.10

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a old version of Pandas (0.10...) and getting the new version will take time as it is an enterprise-wide change.

I am looking to convert a timestamp into mm/dd/yyyy format in Pandas 0.10, and I am at a loss as to_datetime() method does not seem to have format argument.

Can you please suggest a workaround?

Other option would be to have a way to convert the column to mm/dd/yyyy during to_csv() invocation.

Comment: I can't check it on such an old version, but you can try it out: `df['column'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` ...

Comment: that Pandas dataseries in 0.10 does not have .dt either

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105976/get-mm-dd-yyyy-from-pandas-timestamp/19106012#19106012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your old version of Pandas (0.10) doesn't have yet `DateTimeSeries.dt` accessor, you can try this slower approach:

```
In [68]: df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
Out[68]:
0    01/29/2017
1    01/30/2017
2    01/31/2017
4    02/02/2017
0    01/29/2017
1    01/30/2017
2    01/31/2017
3    02/01/2017
Name: dt, dtype: object
```