# python saving xlsx as csv date saves as date time

Tags: python, excel, csv, datetime, xlsx

I need to read an xlsx, format the date from dd-mm-yy to yyyy-mm-dd and then save as csv for the inport to sqllite

I have everything working but when it saves as csv it converts the date to date time, e.g. 2016-11-29 becomes 2016-11-29 00:00:00. How can I have the csv be formatted to only date?

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants

import openpyxl
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

f = r"Services.xlsx"

exc = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
exc.Visible = 0
exc.Workbooks.Open(Filename=f)
exc.Rows("1:1").Select()
exc.Selection.Delete(Shift=constants.xlUp)
exc.Range("K:M").Select()
exc.Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"


exc.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
exc.Quit()

data_xls = pd.read_excel('c:\Data\Programs\Cashflow\Database\Services.xlsx', 'Sheet', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('c:\Data\Programs\Cashflow\Database\Services.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105976/get-mm-dd-yyyy-from-pandas-timestamp). In your case, before calling `to_csv()`, add something like this:

```
data_xls['some_column'] = data_xls['some_column'].map(pd.Timestamp.date)
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks so much. Only issue is I have blanks in the date column so I guess ill need to loop through the data to check if its blank or not then apply the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Sangbok Lee worked but I ran into issues with null entries for my date column. I was able to solve with the following try except

```
try:
    data_xls["Final Report Date"] = data_xls["Final Report Date"].datetime.strptime(data_xls["Final Report Date"], '%d-%m-%Y')
except:
    pd.NaT
```